# How can I color in only specific regions of my scene?

Tags: unity, shaders, graphic-effects

I am interested in having large portions of my game be grayscale, but I'd like certain parts of the scene to have full color.

Something like this:
[image]

Is this something that is possible with shaders or the like within unity? What sort of techniques would I need in order to leech color from most areas like in my screenshot above?

Comment: Which rendering pipeline are you using? The built-in, universal, or HD? The basic idea is similar in all cases (in a post-process pass, blend between the colour image of your scene and its greyscale value using a control mask), but the particulars will vary. It also makes a difference how you want to designate these parts - will it be fixed portions of the screen, particular objects, or spheroidal regions that can partly overlap or be occluded by scene objects, etc...

Comment: @DMGregory I haven't mucked about any with the rendering pipeline, so I assume "the built-in" at the moment. Ideally I'd like the effect to be a radial gradient around particular objects than can overlap, but I'd take radial alone if gradient is extra complicated.

Comment: you can use a [command buffer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/178972/how-to-apply-image-effect-only-on-specific-part-of-objects/178973#178973)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my favourite tricks in Unity is the `OnRenderImage` method. Put this on a script on your camera, and you get to intercept the image the camera has just rendered, and change it any way you like before it gets passed along to the screen or the next rendering pass.

We'll use this to make a script that takes a material and applies it as a post-process effect to the scene:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PostFilter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material filter;

    private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination) {
        if (filter == null)
            Graphics.Blit(source, destination);
        else
            Graphics.Blit(source, destination, filter);        
    }
}
```

Next we need a way to encode which parts of the image should stay colourful. For that, my thought is to use the alpha channel of the image. We'll make a simple shader we can slap on some spheres that will write out a radial gradient into the alpha channel, while keeping the RGB channels the same. I've set this to use Max blending, so if you have two of these gradients overlapping, you'll keep the brighter value.

```
Shader "Unlit/GlowBall"
{
    Properties
    {
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" }
        LOD 100

        BlendOp Max
        ZWrite Off

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float3 normal : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 view : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };
    
            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.normal = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, v.normal);
                o.view = -UnityObjectToViewPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float fresnel = saturate(dot(normalize(i.normal), normalize(i.view)));
                return float4(0, 0, 0, fresnel * fresnel);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

But we want our alpha channel to be zero before these are drawn, so we get fully desaturated colours everywhere else. So we'll write a filter we can use with our post effect script to erase the alpha channel of the rendered scene image:

```
Shader "Effect/Tint"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint Colour", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 0)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // No culling or depth
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            fixed4 _Color;

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                
                return col * _Color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Create a material with this shader, set the tint colour to (1, 1, 1, 0), and assign it as the filter on the `PostFilter` script on your main camera. Now it's outputting the scene image to the screen with the alpha channel blacked-out and ready for our next step.

Next we need to render our glow balls in a second pass, after we've erased the scene's alpha. So we'll duplicate the main camera, and make the new copy a child of the original, so they move together.

Set the clear flags on the new camera to "Don't Clear", and its Depth to 0 (after the default Main Camera's -1), so we draw over the existing scene image).

Set the culling flags so your new camera sees only the glow balls, and the main camera sees everything BUT the glow balls.

So once this camera has rendered, we'll have our scene image, with bright alpha *only* where we have our gradient spheres placed. One last post-effect filter on this child camera will then turn that alpha mask into colour saturation before presenting the image to the screen:

```
Shader "Effect/SelectiveDesaturate"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // No culling or depth
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                float desaturated = dot(col.rgb, float3(0.2126f, 0.7152f, 0.0722f));

                col = lerp(desaturated, col, col.a);

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

You can see these balls will now add saturation to anything inside/behind them, but can still be occluded by desaturated objects in front of them (like the studs at the top of the image, or the grey jigsaw on the right).

[image: Scene with selective saturation]

Comment: This is *super cool* and works perfectly, even for 2d sprites! (Which, duh, because this affects the post-rendered pixels directly) Where might I go to learn more about shaders? I can make *some* sense of the 3 shaders here, but I can't interpret all of them quite yet.