# How to make render texture grayscaled?

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, textures, rendering

I have made a minimap, but I don't know how to make it less colorful and haven't find any solution for this.

Comment: Normally you'd create a material to use when drawing that texture to the screen that desaturates the colour sampled from the texture. You can find many examples of this online. To get help writing your own shader, you should be sure to mention in your question what render pipeline you're using, and whether you're looking for a ShaderLab solution or a shader graph approach.

Comment: I am using a raw image, this is where the material should be attached. The issue is that i have masked it with another image component to make the minimaps shape circular. If I add a shader material to the raw image, it will loose it's circular shape.

Comment: `RawImage` is the name of the component, not the render pipeline. Typical render pipelines would be "Legacy"/"URP (Universal Render Pipeline)"/"HDRP (High-Definition Render Pipeline)". If you don't know which one you're using, then it's probably the legacy pipeline. You can copy the built-in UI shader which supports masking, and modify it to include desaturation. Or you can desaturate the `RenderTexture` contents as a post-process before they're written into the texture, [using an `OnRenderImage` script as shown here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185593/39518)