Unity Grayscale camera but mask colors
I'm trying to replicate the example given in this thread:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185593/179264, and I was able to, but for now I want to implement the "mask" thing to 2d lights and not only sprite renderer in Unity.
What would be the best way or tutorial to achieve this?

You would probably have to do this with some kind of shader, I dont think you can do something like this with just lights

I did with shaders, but it's only working with sprite renderers. I want to find a way to use it with the alpha channel of lights or some like that.

Can you explain what it would mean to implement this mask to 2D lights? Can you mock up an image of what you want it to look like, contrasted against what you have working so far?

For sure!

Here, the red lined is a sprite using the material with the tutorial shader, the sprite is a circular gradient, but with the shader is just solid border.
The pink lined is the same sprite but using default sprite shader, it keeps the gradient, and mask a little, but paint the color too, so not useful.
The green one is a 2D light. I want to use this to achieve effects like candles, fireplaces, cast shadows, etc.
